# Change Height of Item Layout Accordion Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following panel with the layout accordion, How can i change the height of the first item only ? I tried to define the height of the items inside of the panel but it didn't effect on the height of the items. Here is the code:

```
 me.accordion = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            //width: '80%',
            height: 300,
            margin: "0 0 30 10",
            defaults:[{
                layout:'fit',
                height:'100%',
                width:'100%'
            }] ,
            layout: {

                type: 'accordion',
                titleCollapse: true,
                animate: true,
                activeOnTop: true,
                fill : true

            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'dataCollector',
                    autoScroll:true,
                    //autoHeight:true,
                    margins: accordionItemsMargin,
                    store: records[0].dcModule()
                }
                ,
                {
                    xtype: 'costCalculation',
                    margins: accordionItemsMargin,
                    store: records[0].ccModule()
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'publicCloudConnection',
                    margins: accordionItemsMargin,
                    store: records[0].pcModule()
                }

            ]

        });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `height:300` from panel and add `height:300` for first item of the panel. Here is the code.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        //width: '80%'
        //height : 300,
        margin : "0 0 30 10",
        defaults : [{
            layout : 'fit',
            height : '100%',
            width : '100%'
        }],
        layout : {
            type : 'accordion',
            titleCollapse : true,
            animate : true,
            activeOnTop : true,
            fill : true
        },
        items : [{
            xtype : 'dataCollector',
            autoScroll : true,
            height:300,
            //autoHeight:true,
            margins : accordionItemsMargin,
            store : records[0].dcModule()
        }, {
            xtype : 'costCalculation',
            margins : accordionItemsMargin,
            store : records[0].ccModule()
        }, {
            xtype : 'publicCloudConnection',
            margins : accordionItemsMargin,
            store : records[0].pcModule()
        }]
});
```